# Room implementations with kotlin i got error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'    
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'    
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {

    compileSdkVersion 30

    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tryingroom2"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions{
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

}
```

--------------------------------line-------------------------------------------

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

-----------------------My Error---------------------------------------

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kapt'.
> Could not download kotlin-stdlib-1.3.41.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.41/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.41.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/6ea3d0921b26919b286f05cbdb906266666a36f9a7c096197114f7495708ffbc?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22kotlin-stdlib-1.3.41.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNmVhM2QwOTIxYjI2OTE5YjI4NmYwNWNiZGI5MDYyNjY2NjZhMzZmOWE3YzA5NjE5NzExNGY3NDk1NzA4ZmZiYz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmtvdGxpbi1zdGRsaWItMS4zLjQxLmphciUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTYwMzY4OTk4Mn0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=Ehsju~zSK2jMFh5OmdezOwnHAqgBQ1L0yWWOUZNZV2NIH66Kr3ywbX96c9nUfwkdGGHvS7pPQ9reH2yXF30uqXvZhtCNXM9uOCEiqLK02bTc-o-CGlFdO-1Nak34GAbky5wKcFbIz5TaJLKUf65KBE4NFKG940Zpof-MgtDrQJsf4sBajShIg7MmibnO3t0zor5mII69tWDe3Vl0RbyxJzF8zd4NdPnDG133mRjbeE9I4qFJwU~6XVWrGmEMU6hKC3I3NY-xeuajrkJO7Ap3h6YvCAaHM1JKelb6~CkphxVLrnHQt-dgHycdyi7iZ5Y~gHjxHFcIh72hFY0qE~QmNQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download antlr4-4.7.1.jar (org.antlr:antlr4:4.7.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.7.1/antlr4-4.7.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/a2cdc2f2f8eb893728832568dc54d080eb5a1495edb3b66e51b97122a60a0d87?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22antlr4-4.7.1.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYTJjZGMyZjJmOGViODkzNzI4ODMyNTY4ZGM1NGQwODBlYjVhMTQ5NWVkYjNiNjZlNTFiOTcxMjJhNjBhMGQ4Nz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmFudGxyNC00LjcuMS5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDM2OTA2MzZ9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=kOTZR94gFkdDz59lZr63yFacAR7gB40W50YbO9iwIxBu~vhLYVmYSE31AoDev4TXC3V3mc87WInA9qhEkowK9WbbKsPpMkDfb0HoHzwpKEbvZYhMXjLbmH1c-tx8GYFzFqxKTuceVr9142GukzJMxyAjyuqn3dlIGWbtXvuNMl6H3D9qPbY9PN2xk7YjAa9c4GrgRj~k4vdWj3WnKy5rEw~oYVutDT7olstrw-GM8avofgi4wtDCmrl~sif0sUHgP1rcLWmmguebMStWs7Hu3M-cddUpJ3BQ~r4RBVIXUlEIvaQbnMHbjXYYb37XRXXILQYKhGekshIBQT8Uxxq0LQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar (org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.25.2)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.25.2/sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/a45da61abed61568a533fdece125093180828edeb0d4b6f6d572e0cf457465f6?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYTQ1ZGE2MWFiZWQ2MTU2OGE1MzNmZGVjZTEyNTA5MzE4MDgyOGVkZWIwZDRiNmY2ZDU3MmUwY2Y0NTc0NjVmNj9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnNxbGl0ZS1qZGJjLTMuMjUuMi5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDM2OTA2MzZ9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=hYPEYZwfhhSHVq81YyPJVkjwGWZBrkd3iwdYR1z4ud4n1ySvitAJlExRS1GvG4Uq4gcmTgHlMdgYxfxn~GHgwoK8lQaHlrRg01AD03PrZFovXspCTjJFt5rOmVzlnxBU4ZqIscI3g7VkF~B5OOitNd7PEQj-gb8uPR5FH9GQhS7staQnU1F8L-7dugrZDYJJNklMfohaXX8PdlklFAX20Yg8dyIea8a3d-tSryo7Ep3X7dbTyKUInfk5s77kODkuLW-wj3eumfeUlZtlUc4uvgcIq3BEpNtqf1IJQYHpEKWxYTouY~rcZ~1Sc2MXnYqc8YiKeABRoxCXnDdnvGkslg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download gson-2.8.0.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/c6221763bd79c4f1c3dc7f750b5f29a0bb38b367b81314c4f71896e340c40825?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22gson-2.8.0.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYzYyMjE3NjNiZDc5YzRmMWMzZGM3Zjc1MGI1ZjI5YTBiYjM4YjM2N2I4MTMxNGM0ZjcxODk2ZTM0MGM0MDgyNT9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmdzb24tMi44LjAuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjAzNjkwMDE4fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=qrPQrwgDOBkj10SgqrBBIlOxhZsFuC-VlAuls-mDnoBPWbd-~rV53wxWAO~4qu9zKQwl~EkMEajbmNeyPhuGTXIIbrhfYNeS89BhFmDBET5QjYd4FI5jbdkFOhJClIYTV-nliVkQRNsQ9eFldsQMh2YLyzyyRAoQfZ1TgUiUDGfzTAEGh1~4wK9j5nnwgeVWNSqpGPOnA0slYfI6hlotg3B7e8qEfshnDcAjLBf-8TTBmePHj3TCc9A8AZewzjas35ie4EhSRvA7SehvoMG5NfRZ-tsV8RL8Nm9e5FpxlyAKhLRjRtjK30IjXn73bq0h3sFma4N0fscUiC-nN-VV6g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download guava-23.5-jre.jar (com.google.guava:guava:23.5-jre)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/23.5-jre/guava-23.5-jre.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/c9467788effbc7e6b0654a3fd7c7e0444d704664a322d218ea8c7276b16422bb?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22guava-23.5-jre.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYzk0Njc3ODhlZmZiYzdlNmIwNjU0YTNmZDdjN2UwNDQ0ZDcwNDY2NGEzMjJkMjE4ZWE4YzcyNzZiMTY0MjJiYj9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmd1YXZhLTIzLjUtanJlLmphciUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTYwMzY5MDUyMn0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=pVmzdkYwEQq~OD7KJD5Iar~28PSTCJuIQoD2j7IrpnwurprGi7BTSq0M7k2iNTmeGmgHc9ejEm94Wrp20~J0yp2POUTrNWAZa-gARuAZuqCwpsshxnwGgAZjpUh368fYq02-cDhAy1ZM~q8q1gvrkxfzGcWghakxW5Iz-EhKdznjEiHUmvNffSKDsdMeNgtmhhRiEow6TsVRhrseikpA0DhpCnFUnpOX4JhevVLdMUlrFSS2A~WwknZqqywrSMGM71xQUxEfJ9Nzg3tgmqsszPUov0wGk1mz3zUszB9~DGqUobD3LmP66RMu2~pAt5ABR3-uEDRwiL2dFTATmVZGQA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar (org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.7.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.7.1/antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/43516d19beae35909e04d06af6c0c58c17bc94e0070c85e8dc9929ca640dc91d?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNDM1MTZkMTliZWFlMzU5MDllMDRkMDZhZjZjMGM1OGMxN2JjOTRlMDA3MGM4NWU4ZGM5OTI5Y2E2NDBkYzkxZD9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmFudGxyNC1ydW50aW1lLTQuNy4xLmphciUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTYwMzY5MDIwNH0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=K8S8~PVbWUZmw6z~N8vemxWPMB84BR7d9B7o21hyGaUzfWCpslAYXeG0glGANcGFZV5F~lrqIcaLYbzDAo8J-WwSd2CtUJBLolM59DHbwPGLHzdF99UjgxhfauJaxwAhGZQh0WWJjUST7yucP2mi--Wpj2s5glh0Hp~41Wlc6MxKVTsu2d4BuRrY0djJ5Vw~k1jZ36Q~UkACwm57ew8jnsiDgJSA0k1yxt2ipJkwqURItfcvAaqxjAwAI8HClrekW~aNVIodhikfJiOsnUzvOcMfRqDU3c29fBtaDij9q4RSlR9p3ZYg253r1L5ou0Z~jYgCsv~E7HHzPjwpwKkIbg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download ST4-4.0.8.jar (org.antlr:ST4:4.0.8)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.8/ST4-4.0.8.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/0a1c55e974f8a94d78e2348fa6ff63f4fa1fae64?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22ST4-4.0.8.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvMGExYzU1ZTk3NGY4YTk0ZDc4ZTIzNDhmYTZmZjYzZjRmYTFmYWU2ND9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMlNUNC00LjAuOC5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDM2OTA1OTV9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=DWhlJly8F4e1cyTuvwC1HkUoIzAWMIffWiJSpj7g73PjPE2Ap1Si0DigIVBV8tDPkAaJZUlIw5NtI4Ai-PFf~Cg~VsfLYxTiQKgOu5CjfFvCPdrnXyGfbARRhV5pObZvSOdXYEMRd6ybvPHziV~SJWA~7gluZEoMOIotIbSCTEmTQ6QUJvzoTgDZLhTqLhDmssKvXYDksstQVhf-wbXPdgCydDzpybKZWZwSwEgHRn9DYFlnL8HuHzAOvSxDtx520ov4yIu7-H5~dk71FdehY5aY52-JbFBA7L8FCwmpaI5LzVKxn6Reey9ck8Q-InAmVd~m9tv3VAEyG-vyd8a7wg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download icu4j-58.2.jar (com.ibm.icu:icu4j:58.2)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/58.2/icu4j-58.2.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/953e1e83b2be7c3ea2f88da86c13614f47e9e71d3578c8521d7f187756b63962?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22icu4j-58.2.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvOTUzZTFlODNiMmJlN2MzZWEyZjg4ZGE4NmMxMzYxNGY0N2U5ZTcxZDM1NzhjODUyMWQ3ZjE4Nzc1NmI2Mzk2Mj9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmljdTRqLTU4LjIuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjAzNjkwNjM2fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=cxVQEuTcEd~8mpW4GIKmqnkuV6tAifjzJND23ufIxlmWDOkhIfSTTqzaj5XS3Cfa2z6BBNfzSGIgM~9EMih05N-Ac6AeOWlfb48gQ2-t0nFgQARr~vNlSS0lC4dQEtM3JtbbavSbCZE982XJ6SCKlT4nsum20rVHBSYxRXGbi-AoPWHhA7myMF7KprQYib2~EBCIRGPo7THplvVXcDa6pSoR6VLJfeZLJXJSoKxuhMEnyaRM8bJoWQ8BmrjO7c4XF4Y8y0DhsBVbIjawqH7sQoGkrqrPKVAJ8bgGpcOtYnDuy4nkWXdfBV0kxFKdpx0~QB0c3f6p42IpdRFB1QzDIg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.0.0/checker-qual-2.0.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/fc8441632f5fa5537492c9f026d1c8b1adb6a7796f46031b04b4cc0622427995?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22checker-qual-2.0.0.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvZmM4NDQxNjMyZjVmYTU1Mzc0OTJjOWYwMjZkMWM4YjFhZGI2YTc3OTZmNDYwMzFiMDRiNGNjMDYyMjQyNzk5NT9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmNoZWNrZXItcXVhbC0yLjAuMC5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDM2OTAyMDR9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=l~2C7~kGH4gHouJzuMwB2YS1PuL99s3GLSqyTSbz9TCuNv4ejTGNvPsjzVN8oLihW~lCo~IJCoWZ~bUcNQ3NqiqmysXcqer69gCOkXxtk~hsM~qaWm8vnx2DA7o133J1PXwEuqw8DJojSuKOfGb-9R86eKjpQpt4P~FomQIn0opLAOjI0tEoNrv~M6i8iRGBNgUZjgu~kRjYBo921z4fCdQ5nUDkzRNa1gbRmFJ~zyWK2oBDmxZyBCb6IDReUzDNCCxrH0WH93hFv8EBbhnGcXecrrKwgk7ilmfCFO9-aV4ajfdzno1nm4z0W1EEC-CBnnYJXz2bca5SdK5jGDFvkg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
> > Connection reset

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

Comment: I cannot solve this error for the second day already, searching the problem in the internet a long time, nothing works

Comment: As you see the mention of `Could not GET` and `Could not get resource` in the logs, it possibly would be an issue with downloading the dependencies due to a network issue, possibly due to firewall or proxy in your machine.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please update value for ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10" in project level build file this may solve your problem.

Comment: updated, now i have * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'TryingRoom4'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10)

Comment: There is something wrong with downloading. Make sure you have disabled offline mode. If you already disabled offline mode then check your internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

you should upgrade room version from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 :

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"
```